# Navigation menu container not changing to selected variable

Tags: html, wordpress, menu, navigation, nav

At the moment, I have this:

```
<nav><? wp_nav_menu(); ?></nav>
```

And it would be great to have it work like this:

```
<? wp_nav_menu(array("container" => "nav"); ?>
```

So the end result is very clean:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/page-a">Page A</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/page-b">Page B</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/page-c">Page C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So it can remove the div wrapper and change it to a nav tag instead.  I have done a lot of research and it seems as though it's a known problem, whether the Codex isn't written clearly or there really is a bug here.  I've played around with `register_nav_menu()` and doing this doesn't seem to change anything, as well as all the other answers on different forums.  Why is this so hard to do for such a simple thing?

On another note, just because I like code to be very clean and easy to read, is there a way to include the correct spacing as shown above rather than it being in just one long line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nav` var isn't working for me either. I would just use: `'container' => false` instead. This will at least get rid of the additional `<div>` tags within your added `<nav>` tags.

```
<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'homepage', 'container' => false, 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="footer_menu">%3$s</ul>' )); ?>
</nav>
```

`'items_wrap'` will allow you to clean up the output as well. More can be read about this argument here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/any-docs-for-wp-nav-menus-items-wrap-argument/19247#19247

Comment: Not having a problem here with `'container' => false`. This strips out the default `div` around the `ul`. Would need to see your code to assist in any way... Also so: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu